# Migrating to WPEngine

Tags: wordpress, migration

I'm working on migrating our Wordpress site to WPEngine, and I don't know how to get the civi database onto WPEngine. WPEngine doesn't allow the creation of a new database for civi. Has anyone done this before? I have found other topics regarding WPEingine here, but for now I just want to get the database onto WPEngine.

Comment: I would do extensive testing of all your current civicrm uses and all possible future civicrm uses - you may run into a ton of issues. Any reason why you chose WPEngine? (besides that they are a great WP host?)

Comment: WPE was recommended to us and it looked great until now. We're actually moving to a new CRM so using civi on WPE would be temporary. I may want to rethink moving to WPE before changing the CRM because it may be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: WPEngine is great for WordPress hosting. Thats not to say that there arent alternatives that are great too and would work fine with CiviCRM. If you are leaving CiviCRM - **tears** - you may want to consider making that transition first.

Answer (score 1):

I have only used CiviCRM at WPE on test sites.

You will have to share the same DB as WP.

You need to prepare teh backup for restore offline.   That said, I mean that if backed up from another server, the DEFINER (used in Triggers and Routines) have to be stripped out, and the database should be compressed.   You'll need to restore via phpmyadmin from my.wpengine.com

A word of warning, WP Engine reserves the right to change the database user.   When they do this they will update wp-config.php, but not civicrm.settings.php.   This has not happened to me on CiviCRM (keep in mind I only use WPE for testing on CiviCRM) , but it has happened on WP sites I have supported at WPE.

Comment: Thank you, Kevin..... So I export my database from the current host and then I have to edit it to remove the DEFINER statement(s). What's the best tool/application for editing the .sql file? Will any text editor work?

Thanks for the heads-up about the potential for a database user change! Of course, that only matters if I actually get things up and running on WPE.

Comment: we use the following perl script in case it helps your situation: perl -pi -e 's#\/\*\!5001[7|3].*?`[^\*]*\*\/##g'